# Failed login in yii framewok because user id primary key has a foreign key to other table

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, authentication, yii

I have database table in postgresql and yii 
the table is table user and table request. attributes user.id_user is a primary key that refer to request table as Foreign key

> user.id_user is PK that refer to request.id_user (FK)

I submit a request through form and save id_user in request. Then I log out and  then I can't login again with that username and password..

it said

> Incorrect username or password.

I have try with other username and password and it's just like that again..
there is my authenticate code

`

Please tell me what the problem it is and solution for this problem .
thank you..

Comment: so did you debug it for login rules?

Comment: how to do that? sorry I am newbie in Yii.. but I have check if I use an id to login and then I make a request then the user can't log in again after logout..

Comment: ok, first you have to write query for login. Yii is not auto configuring login rules for dynamic data. did you write login query?

Comment: nope.. this is my first time use yii and I copy paste

Comment: o ya.. I used MD5 password encrypt.. is that take effect??

Answer (score 0):

here are login configuration examples

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/45600-yii-autentication-with-mysql/
http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/04/simple-authentication-with-the-yii-framework/

Comment: I have used that configuration.. but it still can't login after I make a request

Comment: so, be sure to every thing is ok. lets debug it. put echo, var_dump(), print_r and die functions in if, after quers... end see the result

Comment: if you let me 2 hours,  will post my login codes. now, i must go to home :)